# Can't access external storage in API-29

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions, android-api-levels

The following code works well in the lower API-29. But when using API-29, it gives access denied to external storage error.

```
public void persistFile(byte[] bytes, String path, String fileName) throws IOException {
    OutputStream fOut = null;
    File picDirectory = new File(path);
    File file = new File(path, fileName); 
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fOut.write(bytes); 
    fOut.flush();  
    fOut.close();  
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

On Android 10 file paths outside of your App's private directories are worthless by default, you can temporarily enable requestLegacyExternalStorage until Android 11 (which is now out in preview)

See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Going forward it is probably best just to use Media Store or Storage Access Framework

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in manifest application tag.

```
<manifest ... >
  <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
       Android 10 or higher. -->
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke: this should not work on Android 11 once your `targetSdkVersion` rises to `30` or higher (or `"R"` in the current developer preview). See https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage#scoped-storage

Comment: Thank you. I see it. :(